# Why dont I have file permission when running conda clean on Windows?

Tags: windows, anaconda, conda, file-permissions

I'm using Anaconda3 and Miniconda on Windows 11. I don't know what happened but my conda seems not to have file permissions when I execute any subcommands.

Specifically, even if I remove a certain package (whether in a virtual environment or not), it always prompts me that the uninstallation is successful, but when I go to the installation directory, I will find that the file of that package is still there.

Another strange thing is that when I run `conda clean --all -y`, it always prompts a long list of warnings that the various packages that have been installed cannot be deleted due to file permission issues. The specific logs are as follows:

```
Will remove 153 (77.9 MB) tarball(s).
Will remove 1 index cache(s).
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\cache
Will remove 28 (62.7 MB) package(s).
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\anyio-3.6.1-py310h5588dad_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\ca-certificates-2022.3.29-haa95532_1
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\certifi-2021.10.8-py39haa95532_2
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\certifi-2022.5.18.1-py310h5588dad_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\certifi-2022.5.18.1-py39hcbf5309_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\certifi-2022.6.15-py310h5588dad_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\conda-4.12.0-py39haa95532_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\conda-content-trust-0.1.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\cryptography-36.0.0-py39h21b164f_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\cython-0.29.28-py310hd77b12b_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\dnspython-1.16.0-py310haa95532_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\eth-hash-0.2.0-py_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\h2-4.1.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\importlib_metadata-4.11.4-hd8ed1ab_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\openssl-1.1.1n-h2bbff1b_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\pip-21.2.4-py310haa95532_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\python-snappy-0.6.0-py310hd77b12b_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\python_abi-3.10-2_cp310
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\python_abi-3.9-2_cp39
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\six-1.16.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\snappy-1.1.9-h6c2663c_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\sqlite-3.38.2-h2bbff1b_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\tqdm-4.63.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\trio-0.19.0-py310haa95532_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\typing-extensions-4.2.0-hd8ed1ab_1
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\ujson-5.1.0-py310hd77b12b_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\urllib3-1.26.8-pyhd3eb1b0_0
WARNING: cannot remove, file permissions: D:\miniconda3\pkgs\vc-14.2-h21ff451_1
There are no tempfile(s) to remove.
There are no logfile(s) to remove.
```

I've always thought it was a file permissions issue, but I'm sure I haven't tweaked these things, they worked fine before (perhaps a win11 issue?). What's more, I tried to set full permissions to all user groups, the problem still exists. So it could be a deeper problem?

At the moment I'm completely clueless as to how to fix this, what tests should I do next to further identify the problem? Or is there any solution to try?

Comment: I have the same issue with Windows 11. Setting the permissions does not help.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely did not start your terminal with full System Administrator privileges.

Tap the Windows "Start" button on your keyboard, then type "cmd" to get a Windows Command Console (cmd.exe), but make sure that you select "Run As Administrator" in order to get full administrator privileges.

Once the window opens up, the Command Console "Title Bar" at the top of the window must say "Administrator: Command Prompt", otherwise you do not have system admin privileges.

[image: Start Windows Command Console, then "Run As Administrator]

You should then see a Command Console window that looks like this:

[image]